# Trouble with C++ templates (big surprise!). Why won't this work?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

I am testing out  a way to mimic C# properties and created the following `property` class:

```
struct BY_REF
{
    template <class T>
    struct TT_s
    {
        typedef T &TT_t;
    };
};
struct BY_VAL
{
    template <class T>
    struct TT_s
    {
        typedef T TT_t;
    };
};

template <class T, class P=BY_REF>
class property
{
private:
    typedef typename P::template TT_s<T>::TT_t TT;
    T &value;
    property();
    property(const property &);
    property &operator=(const property &);
public:
    explicit property(T &v) : value(v) {}
    operator const TT() const
    {
        return value;
    }
    TT operator=(const TT i)
    {
        return value = i;
    }
};
```

I tested this class with the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    std::string s;
    property<int, BY_VAL> I(i);
    property<std::string> S(s);
    //stringproperty S(s);
    I = 1337;
    char c[] = "I am ";
    S = std::string(c);
    cout << /*S <<*/ I << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me an unexpected compiler error, "`no match for 'operator='`...", for the line `S = std::string(c);`. I commented out the printing of `S` because I the `operator=` problem seems to be simpler, and I hope its solution will solve the `operator<<` problem as well. To try to figure out what is going on, I instantiated the template manually as follows:

```
class stringproperty
{
private:
    std::string &value;
    stringproperty();
    stringproperty(const stringproperty &);
    stringproperty &operator=(const stringproperty &);
public:
    explicit stringproperty(std::string &v) : value(v) {}
    operator const std::string &() const
    {
        return value;
    }
    std::string &operator=(const std::string &i)
    {
        return value = i;
    }
};
```

My manual version works. Can anyone explain why the template version doesn't? (I suspect it has something to do with the `BY_REF` and `BY_VAL` classes but then I do not know why it works for integers.)

Comment: do you have "#include <string>" expression in the header of property class?

Comment: Is the error possibly the const part of the expression? (e.g. `const std::string &` != `const TT`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your manual version is erroneous, and the issue has nothing to do with templates.

```
typedef int& IntRef;

const int& == int const&

const IntRef == IntRef const == int& const
```

Notice the difference ? The issue is thus there: `TT operator=(const TT i)`.

The general guideline is that if you want to treat a `typedef` as a simple text replacement, then you need to start *right now*: **Put the `const` after the type it qualifies**.

Comment: The manual version is actually exactly what I intended. How can I fix the template version to reflect this?

Comment: Change the `operator=` to take a `T const&` in any cases. (and I also suggest change its return type, it feels weird that it does not return `*this`)

Comment: Thank you, I fixed this problem.

But now I am stuck with the `ostream::operator<<` problem.

I don't know whether to manually overload it or to find a way to make the conversion work.